# Inversions with "gave this"

Tags: objects

How do you feel a and b? (inversion?)

> Where did you get that?
>   a.Your friend **this gave** to me.
>   b.Your friend **gave this** to me.

What if the sentenses to use "has"?

> Where did you get that?
>   a.Your friend **has this gave** to me.
>   b.Your friend **has gave this** to me.

Comment: Adding "has" breaks both of them. I think you're supposed to pick either "a" or "b" because one of them uses correct grammar and the other does not.

Comment: Only the first b is correct. There is absolutely no inversion in that sentence, and there is no need for it either. The two versions with _has_ are both gibberish - I don't understand what you were trying to accomplish by adding a seemingly random extra verb.

Answer (score 1):

> a1. Your friend this gave to me.

This is the wrong word order.  In English the direct object comes after the verb except in very special cases, like occasionally when writing poetry.

> b1. Your friend **gave this** to me.

This one is correct

> a2. Your friend has this gave to me.

This is the wrong word order and has a superflous "has"

> b2. Your friend has gave this to me.

Also wrong.  Perhaps you were thinking of this correct version:

> Your friend **has given this** to me.